# Unable to create service com.parse.PushService: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, parse-platform

I am using service https://www.parse.com for push notifications. 
The error only appears when the application is closed. On the other hand, the error does not seem to appear when the application is active.

My code:

```
 ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

            // Enable Local Datastore.
            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

            Parse.initialize(this, "cMQIGJhjD58Dn3uQ27nx5NsO***", "f0VtuHy2G1NsWUPrfzkzJjh7523UDnqX7cQav****");
            ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

            ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
            ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
            // Optionally enable public read access.
            // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
            ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.home.smart.home" >


    <permission
        android:name="com.home.smart.home.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.home.smart.home.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Push -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- end Push -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- end Push -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.home.smart.home.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.home.smart.home.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- Push -->

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB0gzAqr_M4y_Iy3_xq6yvu17zpkG7V_IU" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <!-- Push -->

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.home.smart.home" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha"/>

        <!-- end Push -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The error message from Logcat is:

```
Unable to create service com.parse.PushService: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: In what line number does the error occur?

Answer (score 0):

is this:

```
 Parse.initialize(this, "cMQIGJhjD58Dn3uQ27nx5NsOtawsbWy1oxHtYnBn", "f0VtuHy2G1NsWUPrfzkzJjh7523UDnqX7cQavRDw");
            ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

in a different activity (e.g: "Service.java") or in one of your main activities? if it is in one of your main activities, create a new class, called Service, add the above code to it, and add this to your manifest's `<application>` tag:

```
<application
android: name="com.packagename.app.Service"
...
>
...
</application>
```

Comment: if not, provide a full logcat please.

Answer (score 0):

As i see from your *Manifest* file that you don't have a class which extends Application. you have to add a class extends *Application* and add it as name property

Then Add the initialization of *Parse* in this new Class which extends *Application*.